# IAudioVolumeEndpoint setMute will unmute, but never really mute (looks muted while sounds is still heard)

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have a piece of code, which is supposed to mute/unmute sound. I have patched it a lot, so now it enumerate all rendering device to toggle their mute status. However, although it perfectly unmute anything, for muting, the sound mixer will show that devices are muted, however the sound is still playing. On my laptop I have a LED which indicates if sound is muted, and it indactes that it's muted too...

I have had a look at similar C++ code to achieve the same and can't find a difference...

```
var
  deviceEnumerator: IMMDeviceEnumerator;
  MMDevice: IMMDevice;
  EndpointVolume: IAudioEndpointVolume;

  Muted: BOOL;
  R: Integer;
  MMDC: IMMDeviceCollection;
  DC: UINT;
  I: Integer;
begin
  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, nil, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, deviceEnumerator);
  if (deviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(eRender, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE, MMDC) = S_OK) then
  begin
    if MMDC.GetCount(DC) = S_OK then
    begin
      for I := 0 to DC - 1 do
      begin
        if (MMDC.Item(I, MMDevice) = S_OK) then
        begin
          MMDevice.Activate(IID_IAudioEndpointVolume, CLSCTX_ALL, nil, @EndpointVolume);

          if EndpointVolume = nil then
          begin
            OutputDebugString('Unable to get endpoint!!!');
          end
          else
          begin
            R := EndpointVolume.GetMute(Muted); // R = S_OK, always
            R := EndpointVolume.SetMute(not Muted, nil); // R = S_OK always, too
          end;

        end;

      end;
    end;
  end
end;
```

If anyone has an idea about what's wrong... There's not a single call failing, and everything looks like it's muted, so I'm really puzzled...
I also use similar code to raise and lower volume, it works perfectly.

Comment: You say you "patched it a lot." Did you patch it so much that it no longer works? Or did the code ever work at all? If the former, then what change did you make that broke it? Does the comparable C++ code work?

Comment: Actually, "a lot" might be beyond the truth. It never worked for muting. I patched it because initially it would only try to mute/unmute the default device. In an attempt to get it work, I decided to mute/unmute all devices. The comparable C++ code works (I haven't compiled it myself, but I have source and binary, and binary indeed mute the sound). See here: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2012/06/18/muting-all-audio-outputs-with-iaudioendpointvolume.aspx?Redirected=true . To me it does the same, and additionally outputs device name.

Answer (score 1):

This is gonna sound dumb :)  Since you're hearing sound, you're not muting something.  Output the names of the devices you are muting; if the list doesn't match the list from the C++ code, that works, then you know where the problem is.

Comment: Well I'll give it a try later, but basically, there are 2 rendering endpoint on the computer. The C++ code mutes 2 showing their name. My code mutes 2, too (or reports having muted)... And well, it unmutes them properly, and Windows mixers shows them as properly muted... And after using my muting code, the C++ muting code, which shows only unmuted devices, do not show anything anymore when executed (so it considers everything IS muted, though I still hear music)

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm super late, but I think I know what is the problem! Maybe this will help somebody in the future! Basically, don't reuse `Muted` variable as `not Muted` :

```
R := EndpointVolume.GetMute(Muted);
R := EndpointVolume.SetMute(not Muted, nil);
```

Use something like this:

```
R := EndpointVolume.GetMute(Muted);
Bool bMuted = Muted;
R := EndpointVolume.SetMute(not bMuted, nil);
```

Or this:

```
R := EndpointVolume.GetMute(Muted);
R := EndpointVolume.SetMute(Muted = 0, nil);
```

What I think is happening, you (and me too, in C++!) are inverting BOOL (that is actually signed int) with `not` or ~ in C++ (like I did). `GetMuted` returns -1 on Mute ON and 0 on Mute OFF. When you invert 0 into -1 and send it to `SetMute`, something bugs out. It seems that `SetMute` is expecting to get 0 for false and 1 for true (not -1!). Undocumented quirks, I guess...

Comment: Interesting, thanks for posting this! If I can find this code again I'll give it a go. I'll likely just send 0 or 1 casted as BOOL for testing.